# How to reset useState everytime I change my page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a Hamburger Navbar
here is my page look like:

[image]

the issues is whenever I clicked to another route but the navbar still appear on right side. I want to make it whenever I go to another route it will disappear.

Here is my code:

```
const App = (props) => {
    const [ menuOpen, setMenuOpen ] = useState(false);

            <HamburgerNav>
                <HamburgerNavContainer>
                    <LogoLinkStyled to="/">
                        <LogoNav src="https://thebeuter.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/logo-black.png" />
                    </LogoLinkStyled>
                    <HamburgerUtilities>
                        <HamburgerUlityItem>
                            <Icon className="fal fa-search fa-rotate-90" onClick={openModalHandler} />
                        </HamburgerUlityItem>
                        <HamburgerUlityItem>
                            <Link to="/cart" style={{ color: 'black', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                                <Icon className="fal fa-shopping-bag" />
                                <CartNumb>({props.basketProps.basketNumbers})</CartNumb>
                            </Link>
                        </HamburgerUlityItem>
                        <HamburgerUlityItem>
                            <HamburgerLine onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} />
                        </HamburgerUlityItem>
                    </HamburgerUtilities>
                </HamburgerNavContainer>
            </HamburgerNav>
```

How can I fix this problem? Really appreciate it.!!!
Github project: https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

update Router code:

Here is my Router for all routes in navbar

```
<Router>
    <ContactForm path="/contact" />
    <SizeChart path="/size-chart" />
    <ShippingAndReturn path="/shipping-return" />
    <PrivacyAndPolicy path="/privacy-policy" />
    <AboutUs path="/about-us" />
    <ShopAllProducts path="/" />
    <NewArrival path="/shop/new-arrival" />
    <Tops path="/product-category/top" />
    <Bottoms path="/product-category/bottom" />
    <Product path="/product/:title_url" />
    <SearchInfo path="/search/:title" searchTerm={searchTerm} title="Profile" />
    <Cart path="/cart" />
    <Checkout path="/checkout" />
</Router>
```

Comment: When you initially open the page is it closed?

Comment: And which component is the "route" component that when you click it doesnt close it?

Comment: all the routes @Dark

Comment: If i want to close it i have to click 1 more time to the `<HamburgerLine>`

Comment: That is probably because you dont have another onClick event to the other components. If for example you want it to close when you click on "T-Shirts", then "T-Shirts" must also have that onClick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add onClick to the "route" component that is not closing it and do something like this:

```
onClick={() => { setMenuOpen(prevState => {return !prevState}) }}
```

If for example you want it to close when you click on "T-Shirts", then "T-Shirts" must also have that onClick.

If you already have onClicks on these components with another function, you can just add multiple functions inside the anonymous function like this:

```
onClick={() => {
  YourOtherFunction();
  setMenuOpen(prevState => {return !prevState});
}
```

If your components are not in the App.js you need to somehow pass the onClick down too them.

Since its a state you wont be able to pass down the setMenuOpen itself, you need a wrapper function. So first create the wrapper:

```
const setMenuOpenWrapper = () => { 
  setMenuOpen(prevState => return { !prevState });
}
```

Then pass it down to the childrens like:

and then inside your ContactForm on the link to the contact form add the onClick:

```
...onClick={() => { closeMenuFunction(); }}
```

Ok I just checked your code, you need to pass down the function to the Sidenav component.

So in your App.js first create the wrapper function as I explained above

After that again in App.js on line 316 where you have `<SideNav menuOpen={menuOpen} />` change it to `<SideNav menuOpen={menuOpen} closeMenuFunction={setMenuOpenWrapper}/>`

Then in your Sidenav.jsx on all of your menu items add an onclick:

```
onClick={props.closeMenuFunction}
```

And then it should work.

Comment: I just add my router in the navbar!!

Comment: Check my answer again, one of these solutions should help you, you just need to find a way to add the setMenuOpen function as an onClick to your links

Comment: Thats in the code that renders these elements. Show me the code that renders T-Shirts for example?

Comment: Check the answer again, I checked your code and added step by step what you have to do.